# Unwanted characters in log file

Tags: java, logging

The simple programm (windows system) add some logging info into file on local disc:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        log("\r\n");
        log("Some string.");
        log("\r\n");
        log("...................................");

    }

    private static void log(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
```

The log file contains unwanted characters. How to avoid them?

> log::11_12_15_::[][][]
>
> log::11_12_15_::Some string.[] log::11_12_15_::[][][]
>
> log::11_12_15_::...................................[]

p.s. where the [] symbols is square character

Comment: What are the original strings that you sent to output ?

Comment: remove the \r\n from the log Statements.

Comment: @Berger what do you mean? original string will look like `"some string\r\n"`

Comment: @Jens I need line breaks in log file.

Comment: As stated above by Jens, remove your line endings, the logger is in charge of the line breaks.

Comment: @Ferro The linefeed should be part of the pattern in your logger configuration

Comment: @Jens the problem was in my custom formatter. the lines ends with `\n` and after I changed them to `\r\n` and removing additions characters in `log()` I finally got it.